# Thunderbird: What is the difference between "Apply Columns to" and "Apply current view to"?

Tags: thunderbird

In Mozilla Thunderbird, what is the **difference** between  "Apply Columns to" and "Apply current view to"?

[image: "Apply Columns to" vs. "Apply current view to"]

Using: Thunderbird 112.0b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Thunderbird options relate to the viewing of columns in message lists,
and allow the current list settings to be applied to all or some folders.

- **Apply current view to** : Relates to the
  current thread view (enabled or disabled).
- **Apply Columns to** : Relates to the selected display columns and their
  order.

References :

- [Message threading in Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-threading-thunderbird#w_applying-threading-to-other-folders)
- [Message List Columns](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-list-columns)
- [How to change the Thunderbird layout](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-thunderbird-layout)

Comment: I think that the "Apply current view to" does NOT apply the Layout (Classic, Wide, Vertical) to the other folders. I just tested it, and the Layout chosen in Menu/View/Layout is fixed for all folders, regardless of what folder is selected when you make the change.

So, the only effect "Apply current view to" has is to threaded/unthreaded? That seems a bit meager to justify an entire, insufficiently named, menu-item, that also lacks a badly needed tool-tip.

Comment: @PeterLairo: Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That seems to confirm that the "Apply current view to" provides very little benefit, especially compared to the uncertainty and confusion it causes.

Comment: Maybe "Apply current view to" also applies the Sort Order?

Comment: It doesn't - just tried it. Truly a useless option. Maybe it did more in the past, but not any more.